# delete some special character from a string by javascript

Tags: javascript

How we can delete some special character from a string by javascript

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to replace it, either using a string or regular expression.

**String:**

```
// JavaScript Document
var string = 'Hello world!';
alert( string.replace( 'world', '' ) ); // Alerts "Hello !"
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
// JavaScript Document
var string = 'Hello world!';
alert( string.replace( /o/, '' ) ); // Alerts "Hell wrld!"
```

Comment: if i want to remove h, o & w then.

Comment: If you want to remove all occurences of h, o and w, use a regular expression that matches for any of those three characters. To do that, wrap the characters in square brackets - e.g. alert ('hello world!'.replace (/[how]/, '')); - I think that's right for Javascript.

Comment: @Arpan Steve314 is right, though I've never seen the `.replace` used directly on a string. /[how]/ is the regular expression you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

if the string to get cleaned up is mystring;

mysring =  mystring.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');

will remove all charectes other than alpahnumeric from your string.
You can modify the regular expression accordingly if you wan tot exclude some special characters from cleaning up.